# Ifelse for Multiple Columns in DataFrame

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, tidy

I have a dataset like the following:

| ID | Winter | Spring | Summer | Fall |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | high | NA | high | low |
| 2 | low | high | NA | low |
| 3 | low | NA | NA | low |
| 4 | low | high | NA | low |

I would like to add a calculated column so that if any of the winter, spring, summer, and fall columns contains "high," then "1" is added to that row as shown below. Otherwise it will contain 0.

| ID | Winter | Spring | Summer | Fall | calculated_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | high | NA | high | low | 1 |
| 2 | low | high | NA | low | 1 |
| 3 | low | NA | NA | low | 0 |
| 4 | low | high | NA | low | 1 |

So far I have something like this, I know it's incorrect. I'm not sure how to specify multiple columns rather than just one:

```
df$calculated_column <- ifelse(c(2:5)=="High",1,0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
     mutate(calculated_column = +(if_any(-ID, ~ . %in% 'high')))
```

-output

```
df1
 ID Winter Spring Summer Fall calculated_column
1  1   high   <NA>   high  low                 1
2  2    low   high   <NA>  low                 1
3  3    low   <NA>   <NA>  low                 0
4  4    low   high   <NA>  low                 1
```

---

Or if we want to use `base R`, create the logical condition with `rowSums` on a logical matrix

```
df1$calculated_column <-  +(rowSums(df1[-1] == "high", na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Winter = c("high", "low", "low", "low"
), Spring = c(NA, "high", NA, "high"), Summer = c("high", NA, 
NA, NA), Fall = c("low", "low", "low", "low")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for me. I used the base R method. Follow-up question, what if I need to select just two columns? Something like this doesn't quite seem to do it: ```df1$calculated_column <-  +(rowSums(df1[c(2,4)] == "high", na.rm = TRUE) > 0)```

Comment: @ava it gives me `+(rowSums(df1[c(2,4)] == "high", na.rm = TRUE) > 0)#
[1] 1 0 0 0`

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
df1$calculated_column = +grepl('high', do.call(paste, df1))
df1
  ID Winter Spring Summer Fall calculated_column
1  1   high   <NA>   high  low                 1
2  2    low   high   <NA>  low                 1
3  3    low   <NA>   <NA>  low                 0
4  4    low   high   <NA>  low                 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `base R` solution:

```
calculated_column = (apply(df1,1,function(x) sum(grepl("high",x)))>0)*1

cbind(df1, calculated_column)
```

```
  ID Winter Spring Summer Fall calculated_column
1  1   high   <NA>   high  low                 1
2  2    low   high   <NA>  low                 1
3  3    low   <NA>   <NA>  low                 0
4  4    low   high   <NA>  low                 1
```